# If I change the classes attributes , will django automatically change the database structure?

Tags: python, database, django

I am new to django so i am little bit confused with database syncing.
Suppose i have 5 class attributes initially and i used site for 2 days and data is in database.
Then i removed 2 attributes and added 3 more attributes.

I want to know that how will then Django handle

1. The data which is already there for removed columns
2. The new columns which were not there before. so will it enter null data in database for the data rows which were there before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you can be confused. The [documentation for syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) clearly states, in a big box, "Syncdb will not alter existing tables".

Use something like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to change existing tables.

Comment: learning to use South should be high on the list of things to learn when starting Django. Oh how much data entry I could have saved myself from...

Answer (score 0):

or use manage.py reset *appname* if data in the tables can be truncated